# self-contained environment like cygwin / git bash

Tags: linux, virtualization

I would like to be able to run a full-featured UNIX/Linux environment inside a Windows 10 environment.

Due to increasing security restrictions, we are very limited in what we can run.  We are unable to run WSL1 or 2, virtualization software no longer runs (used to run w/o network connectivity).

Our desktop engineering team (which is Windows users only) has presented using Visual Studio through a docker container which is all well in good if you only do 1 thing at a time.

Are there any alternative approaches to running Linux software in windows if I am unable to run either WSL1 or 2 or virtualization software?  I can run cygwin / git-bash, but I would also like to use tools like meld.  These increasing limitations make it exceedingly frustrating to develop.  I wouldn't mind it if our processes were automated, but the tools that are selected for us require manual work instead of writing a shell script

Answer (score 1):

Many Linux tools also have Windows releases.

An example is [Meld](https://meldmerge.org/) that you mentioned, but there are
very good Windows alternatives for it such as
[WinMerge](https://winmerge.org/).

If you are only looking for tools, Windows also has plenty of them.
Many have portable versions that do not require installation or Administrator
privileges to use.

My best advice is to adapt yourself to your environment, rather than try to
make it into a clone of your previous one.

Comment: I am posting here as to not disagree with @harrymc.  All of the alternates are crap IMHO.  cygwin / git-bash / ming32 / whatever are poor replacements for the original posix versions.  I am a windows guy and have deep roots in *nix also.  Nothing will be 100% ... I would suggest taking on the war with your internal Gestapo.  The lockdown isn't helping the parent company to make money or to keep things more secure (the only point).

Comment: I am looking for more portable apps in a central place, or the ability to run a self-contained environment.

Comment: You will find many of then in [PortableApps.com](https://portableapps.com/).